# java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread on Unit testing

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a unit test on inserting records to datastore using Objectify but I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread every time I run the test or even trying to run it on Dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `LocalServiceTestHelper` initializing `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig` and call `setup()` before doing any Objectify calls :

```
public class LocalDatastoreTest {

  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  private void doTest() {
    // Objectify calls will work here.
  }

}
```

See also https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting